# How to make a full screen terminal with termlib.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm experimenting with [mass:werk termlib.js](http://www.masswerk.at/termlib/index.html)

I'm interested in accomplishing something [similar to this example](http://cb.vu/), but am unsure how to style it full screen and already opened when the page loads.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place either. This went right over my head.

Comment: No idea why they migrated it from SO - it definitely belongs there. It is a programming question.

Comment: @Charles it was migrated FROM ux TO so

Comment: @Charles sorry, i did not see that post. good call =]

Comment: @Ret The "admin nazis" are regular users, and there is a process to reopen a question if you believe it was closed in error. Calling people "nazis" is not that process, nor is it very professional.

Comment: @Ret This site works how it works, being snotty to me or calling people nazis isn't going to change it, nor does it give you much credibility on the subject. There are other sites, it's a big internet. This question lacks detail. I tried to answer it (5 years ago) as you can see, who knows if I guessed what he needed correctly. The question standards exist for a reason.

Comment: @Ret That isn't a good example because the dupe answers your question clearly. Stop calling people nazis. It's literally insane and highly offensive. The users who closed your question as a dupe, rightly, did not participate in genocide. Slow down, read more carefully, and get some perspective.

Comment: @Ret I mean... how is this NOT a duplicate? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267564/how-can-i-delete-a-stack-exchange-account-of-mine -- the answer there clearly answers the question, which is clearly the same as your question. But don't let that stop you from drawing comparisons between Stack Overflow and the systemic murder of millions of people based on their ethnicity. With all the respect due here, none, please, click the duplicate link, read the answer, and start the delete process. We won't miss you.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "style it full screen"?  If you mean that you want your terminal to have the entire width and height of the viewport, then adding css to this effect:

```
body, #terminal_container {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Should suffice in making a div with the id `terminal_container` consume the entire height and width of the document.

If you mean rather that you want to force "fullscreen" as in the browser full screen with no toolbars (F11 key in Firefox), then the answer is "no, you can't".  There is no way to change the user's client view mode from a website script.  This is a good thing - do you really want websites deciding you don't need your back button anymore?  The user's client options are strictly the domain of the user.